# Cant fint next button on linkedin

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, linkedin-api

I am trying to scrape LinkedIn website using selenium and Beautiful Soup.
The idea is simple, I started in the company's LinkedIn website then go to company search and scroll to the bottom of the page to get all results on the page.

But because Linkedin just provides 10 people per page so I need to find the next button on that page to go to the next 10 people.

I use this code

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('next')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "LinkedInWebcrawler2019.py",
>   line 71, in 
>       nextt = browser.find_element_by_class_name('next')   File "C:\Users\Afdal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
>       return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)   File "C:\Users\Afdal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 978, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']   File "C:\Users\Afdal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\Afdal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":".next"}   (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.75)

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read How to Ask. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  Maybe the site-under-test is blocking you because you are scraping their site...

Answer (score 0):

Try this for finding the next button.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


       Next =WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,'//*[contains(@class,'button')'))
       Next.click()
```

Comment: i got this error 

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="artdeco-button__text">...</span> is not clickable at point (780, 266). Other element would receive the click: <div class="msg-conversation-card msg-overlay-list-bubble__convo-card">...</div>

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the inbox chat window is hindering the click on next button. see updated answer - added dynamic wait.